# Generate .i file from .c file

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I know that gcc does that. But I would want a C program that can do so. The program should accept a .c file and does the preprocessing operations and generate .i file
FYI : this is a project that was assigned to my kin in his college.

Comment: Why? What is the problem you want to solve? Why can't you simply use `gcc -E`? Or do you want to implement your *own* preprocessor?

Comment: GCC is a C program... so...

Comment: @StoryTeller no it's a (surprise) C++ program. Though older versions are C.

Comment: @n.m. - Color me surprised. So no bootstrapping in C?

Comment: @StoryTeller not only that, but you now can only bootstrap with another gcc (not another C or C++ compiler).

Comment: Yes I would like to write my own program but does the exact job of a preprocessor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the command `cc -E file.c -o file.i` this will give you preprocessed file. For more info refer [man](http://man.he.net/?topic=gcc&section=all) page.

Just read your question again. You want to write program, which created that file. 
well you have to do lot of work for that.First of all you need to read `#include` ,  `#define` and Conditional inclusions (`#if, #elif #endif`) and then you need to detect `< >` and `" "`, read the file which is inside these symbols. then you have to `fopen()` those files and paste them into .i file.

TO sum it up it will be a lot of work but that's the way to do it.

**Edit** it is not just copy past. Reading the header file means that inside #include now say your header is abc.h, then you have to search for all predefined location where a .h file can be present. If it is found you need to fopen() that file read its content and write it into your .c file. Plus you have to take care of macros and condtional inclusion. Trust me i have tried it, its lot of work. but you can try it will boost up your basic

Comment: Yes. I would want to write the program..Reading the header files? means I need to just copy paste everything from the header files to the .i file?

Comment: **FYI : this is a project that was assigned to my kin in his college.** The professor might have given some condition to do this project.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use external program such as gcc, you have to implement C preprocessor yourself. Whole preprocessor is described in [C Programming Language specification](https://www.iso.org/standard/57853.html) in section "Preprocessing directives".

Alternatively, if you cannot use other programs, but you don't want to implement it yourself, you could try using [libclang](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1Preprocessor.html) as a library (although, for that you'd need C++).